# why can't i use or mutate new column created in R data.table?

Tags: r, data.table

I want to use/mutate `obs` column i created in the data.table but returns an error

`Error in eval(jsub, SDenv, parent.frame()) : object 'obs' not found`

please see implementation with example data.

```
library(data.table)

set.seed(0)

dt <- data.table(
  index = sample(0:100, 10, replace=FALSE), 
  value = 1:100)

dt[, `:=`(obs = seq_along(index)-1, window = floor(obs/10))] #create an index of every observation and bin them
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`data.table`'s `:=` operator doesn't allow referencing recently-added/changed variables within the same `[`-expression. To do what you want, you need another `[`.

```r
dt[, `:=`(obs = seq_along(index) - 1)
  ][, `:=`(window = floor(obs/10))]
#      index value   obs window
#      <int> <int> <num>  <num>
#   1:    13     1     0      0
#   2:    67     2     1      0
#   3:    38     3     2      0
#   4:     0     4     3      0
#   5:    33     5     4      0
#   6:    86     6     5      0
#   7:    42     7     6      0
#   8:   100     8     7      0
#   9:    81     9     8      0
#  10:    58    10     9      0
#  ---                         
#  91:    13    91    90      9
#  92:    67    92    91      9
#  93:    38    93    92      9
#  94:     0    94    93      9
#  95:    33    95    94      9
#  96:    86    96    95      9
#  97:    42    97    96      9
#  98:   100    98    97      9
#  99:    81    99    98      9
# 100:    58   100    99      9
```

Since this is only doing one assignment per-`[`, we can opt to reduce those visually to

```r
dt[, obs := seq_along(index) - 1
  ][, window := floor(obs/10)]
```

Comment: ok. so this isn't supported by `data.table`! thanks

Comment: Nor is it supported by `base::transform`, it appears to be only `dplyr::mutate` that allows one to immediately reference same-call assignments. (I've actually run into mini-bugs in my code that were because of this feature in dplyr, so it's not always a good thing :-)

Comment: Of course an excellent answer to OP's question, I suggest to use `.I` instead of `seq_along(index)` within the scope of `data.table` and out of the scope of the `data.table` use `obs %/% 10` instead of `floor(obs / 10)`

Comment: @MerijnvanTilborg thank you, that's a good suggestion for the OP. Not relevant here, but I tend to use `seq_along(.)` or `seq.int(.N)` when I'm using grouping, since `.I` is global and not per-group. (There was a suggestion to add `.i` (lower-case) as a per-group row sequence, not sure if that will ever be added.)

Answer (score 6):

You can do this using the `{}` option. Its probably more useful when you want to create an intermediate column that you don't want to retain.

```
dt[, c("obs", "window"):={obs=seq_along(index)-1; window=floor(obs/10); .(obs, window)}]
```